# Add value to every row contains specific string

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables which are related with each other. First table contains `postID` and `fileID`. Second table contains `postID` which are the same values like in the previous table.

What I want to do is:

Select every `postID` in first table where `fileID` is equal to `XXX`. And now with selected rows I want to substract every `fileID` row by `10000`.

Ok, lets say It selected 10 rows and 10 `postID` were substracted by 10000 value. The thing is that I want to substract the same `postID` in the second table.

Im newbie in mysql and I dont know how to deal with it. Can you help me?

Input table1 
[image]

Input table2
[image]

Output table1 
[image]

Output table1 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Select every postID in first table where fileID is equal to XXX.

```
SELECT postID FROM table1
WHERE fileID = XXX;
```

Pretty straightforward.

> And now with selected rows I want to substract every fileID row by 10000.

```
SELECT postID, (fileID-10000) FROM table1
WHERE fileID = XXX;
```

Assuming that `fileID` is a numeric type, and `fileID-10000` is also a valid value for that type (e.g., if it's unsigned, that value won't be negative), this is also pretty straightforward.

> Ok, lets say It selected 10 rows and 10 postID were substracted by 10000 value. The thing is that I want to substract the same postID in the second table.

Ok, you were subtracting fileIDs earlier, but I think what you want is:

```
SELECT table1.postID, table1.fileID, table2.postID-10000 FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.postID = table2.postID
WHERE table1.fileID = XXX;
```

with the same limitations on `table2.postID` as noted above.

*Example*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
postID int,
fileID int
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TABLE table2 (
postID int
);

-- Two different postIDs with the same fileID
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33), (4, 44), (20, 22);

-- postIDs 2 and 20 match postIDs in table1, which have the same fileID 22
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1), (2), (20);

SELECT table1.postID, table1.fileID, table2.postID-10000 FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.postID = table2.postID
WHERE table1.fileID = 22;
```

This gives an output of:

```
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| postID | fileID | table2.postID-10000 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
|      2 |     22 |               -9998 |
|     20 |     22 |               -9980 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

As mentioned in comments, the end goal is to order `postID`s by which contain a particular `fileID`. This could also be accomplished using an [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) statement. For example,

```
SELECT table1.postID, table1.fileID
FROM table1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN fileID = 22 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

Results in all rows, sorting ones with a `fileID` of `22` first:

```
+--------+--------+
| postID | fileID |
+--------+--------+
|      2 |     22 |
|     20 |     22 |
|      1 |     11 |
|      3 |     33 |
|      4 |     44 |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I did that and it says it returned 0 rows .

Comment: Hm, this seems to work on my test data. Can you give a sample input/output example?

Comment: `SELECT cms_file.postId, cms_file.fileId, cms_post.postId-10000 FROM cms_post
INNER JOIN cms_file ON cms_file.postId = cms_post.postId
WHERE cms_file.fileId = '60e6973';`


cms_file is mentioned table1 and cms_post is table2.

Comment: That looks like the same form. And you've confirmed that there are common postIds between cms_file and cms_post for that fileId? I'll add my test case above.

Comment: Ok, let me tell you what I want to do:
postID is an order how posts are ordered. The newest posts are these with highest postID. I want to make posts which contains `XXX` in fileId as oldest. So i have to substract postId by value which will make results  below 0.
But i have to substract the same amount to the same rows in table2.
So:
This is my table 1:
http://puu.sh/pKlmN/955dafaf62.png
and this is my table 2:
http://puu.sh/pKlAD/e298a3aa05.png
So I have to substract B3 by 30000 and B5 by 30000 in table 1 and do the same in A3 and A5 in table 2

Comment: I can't view those links, firewall restrictions :( Perhaps you could edit into the question as text or using the SO upload image? Thanks for the additional info, though. Have you looked at using `ORDER BY`? It might be a more "natural" choice to force the ordering you want. Is your expected output all rows but with only some -30000, or only rows that have been subtracted?

Comment: Yes sure I added table 1 and table 2 in first post. Right now I have 30000 postId, but about 30% contains XXX as fileId. I would like to make them last displayed, so i would have to change their postId value to lowest compared to other, which are not contains XXX. Is it possible to do with `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I added an `ORDER BY` example in my update yesterday, if you want to sort the matching results to the end just swap the 0 and 1. If that does not solve your problem, I'm not sure what you are asking for - please add the desired output from your example tables to your question.

Comment: Ok, I added input and output pictured to first post. Is is possible to order with my needs?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can update multiple tables in a single query by using joins in the table expression part of the update statement:

```
update t1 inner join t2 on t1.postID=t2.postID
set t1.postID=t1.postID-10000, t2.postID=t2.postID-10000
where t1.fileID=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the postId values from second table corresponding to the postId values selected in first table by using a query like this,

```
SELECT * FROM second_table_name
WHERE postId IN (
    SELECT postId FROM first_table_name
    WHERE fileId=xxx
);
```

You can add whatever operation you want to perform in this select query.